# Module Instantitions for simulation

Tags: verilog

I want to simulate a module that has a simple Addr/Data interface.  I want to create a separate module that will act as a transactor for this module.  So for example, I can simply call a task in the transactor module that will perform a write of an addr and data.  e.g.

```
Transactor.Write_Task(0, 123); //Writes 123 to Addr 0.
```

My question is, should I do an `include` to include the transactor module at the top of the testbench?  Or is it a better approach to compile the transactor separately and instantiate it and wire it up, as if it was another unit under test? e.g:

```
\lib_Local_Bus.Local_Bus_Transactor Transactor
   (
    .i_LB_Clk(w_LB_Clk),
    .o_LB_CS(w_LB_CS),
    .o_LB_Wr_Rd_n(w_LB_Wr_Rd_n),
    .o_LB_Addr8(w_LB_Addr8),
    .o_LB_Wr_Data(w_LB_Wr_Data),
    .i_LB_Rd_Data(w_LB_Rd_Data),
    .i_LB_Rd_DV(w_LB_Rd_DV)
    );
```

I feel like it's easier to simply include it with an `include`, but then I need to point to it correctly, which could be a problem.  By precompiling it, instantiating it like a UUT, and wiring it up, there's more code, but it is more straightforward as to what is going on.

Comment: Why don't you compile the two files together as two separate files?

Comment: @Ari, I believe that's essentially what I'm doing in the place where I use the `include`.  Each the transactor and the testbench are in their own files.  When I include the transactor in the TB it compiles them together.

Comment: Where is the test that will call these tasks in relation to the top of the testbench? Do you have access to SystemVerilog? It has a lot of features to help you organize the testbench and make it more re-usable.

Comment: @dave_59, In the simplest case, the testbench will call these tasks.  Yes, I can use SystemVerilog.  What features do you mean?  Can you show me an example?

Comment: All of them :) It will take me a while to get a response to this.

Comment: @dave_59 I would really appreciate being shown a simple example of some features that I may not know.  I don't necessarily need to see *all* of them.

Comment: @Russel Is there a reason you have your transactor as a module and not a class? If it might be better in this situation to use a class to encapsulate all your memory interface transactions. If you want to be really fancy, you use OVM and use its suggested framework (good thing you have SystemVerilog!)

Comment: @unn I think you are correct.  Using classes is the way to go.  I'm going to look into this more, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The classic approach is to treat it as any other module, meaning it lives as its own file and you instantiate the transactor and the DUT together in your top level test bench.  This is how most vanilla Verilog environments I have worked on are coded.

The module can either present a queue-based interface to queue transactions into, or a task-based interface which can then be called from your test, e.g.

```
  initial
    begin : test_block
      Transactor.Send(data1);
      ->stimulus_complete;
    end
```